# Cleaning-up of Bounded queue in ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

While reading the docs for Threadpool executor i see below :

> Two supplied methods, remove(java.lang.Runnable) and purge() are available to assist in storage reclamation when large numbers of queued tasks become cancelled.

I understand that while i can use these methods for cleaning up the worker queue if any tasks are cancelled.
I am trying to understand which part in the actual source does this cleaning up **automatically**.
Suppose i start with a queue of 10, and out of them 4 tasks are cancelled, when the new task arrive, will the queue size be 6 or will it just ignore the 4 cancelled task and reset to 10.

From the source i see this comment :

```
/**
 * Tries to remove from the work queue all
 * tasks that have been cancelled. This method can be useful as a
 * storage reclamation operation, that has no other impact on
 * functionality. Cancelled tasks are never executed, but may
 * accumulate in work queues until worker threads can actively
 * remove them. Invoking this method instead tries to remove them now.
 * However, this method may fail to remove tasks in
 * the presence of interference by other threads.*
 */ 
 public void purge() {
```

But can someone please show me where do the worker threads actively remove the cancelled task in the source ?

Thank you for your time,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The worker threads will actively remove the cancelled tasks during normal operation, when they take() the tasks from the work queue in ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(), and attempt to run() them.  When the underlying FutureTask representing the Runnable unit of work calls its FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(), it first checks for the expected READY state - otherwise it returns. So the execution is skipped if the task was cancelled, and it has already been removed from the workQueue. If the task is already running, the mayInterruptIfRunning flag to FutureTask.cancel() determines whether an interrupt() is attempted.

This means that, by default, the cancelled tasks sit around in the workQueue until an available Worker attempts to process it, finds out the task was cancelled, and completes its processing. So the answer to your question about the queue size depends on whether a Worker has reached any of those tasks. ThreadPoolExecutor.purge() allows you to manually trigger an immediate traversal of the workQueue to remove the cancelled tasks.

Comment: Thanks @Buzz this makes perfect sense. I am checking the code, and i see what you mean.. Thanks again